# Why echo function have two ways to use it?

Tags: php, echo

Lastly I was really wondering why in PHP I can use two ways to use echo function. First one:

```
<?php
echo ("Hello World!");
?>
```

And second:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>
```

The second one makes no sense for me as from what I heard we pass function arguments within the brackets.

Comment: `echo` is not a function, (it is a language construct)

Comment: syntactic conventions i guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the PHP manual:

echo() is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you are not required to use parentheses with it. echo() (unlike some other language constructs) does not behave like a function, so it cannot always be used in the context of a function. Additionally, if you want to pass more than one parameter to echo(), the parameters must not be enclosed within parentheses.

http://www.php.net/echo

Answer (score 0):

> echo() is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you
>   are not required to use parentheses with it.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php):

> **echo()** is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you are not required to use parentheses with it.

Answer (score 0):

The echo() function is not actually a function, so you are not required to use parentheses with it. However, if you want to pass more than one parameter to echo(), using parentheses will generate a parse error.

**echo()** also has a **shortcut syntax**, where you can immediately follow the opening tag with an equals sign. This short syntax only works with the short_open_tag configuration setting enabled.

```
I have <?=$foo?> foo.
```

Answer (score 0):

See, to type as little as [php.net/echo](http://php.net/echo) in the address bar of your browser will give you an answer without asking a whole question. 
It is faster, more reliable and require less efforts saving you from typing all these examples.

I don't understand it. Why do you prefer this amateur site over official manual page?